# How does firebase rule set protects database?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

If i have authentication enabled, and a person authenticated using the sign in method being use does that mean he can still manipulate my database within the browser console? Or only if firebase exposed globally? I asking specifically with react js development.

Answer (score 3):

If you set the rules like this:

```
{
"rules": {
   ".read":true ,
   ".write": true
 }
}
```

It just means that anyone can read and write to the database. It does not mean that they can access the firebase console where the database is. And also it does not mean if they took the firebase database url, then they can access your database- they cant since the database is associated with your account.

Only people that have access to your account can enter the firebase console and change rules and/or your database in the console.

Do this as a test, log out of your account and take the firebase database url and enter it in the `url` above and see if you will be able to access it.

An Example with the above rules: If you have a login screen in your website then even using the above rules the user cannot just login, since in your code you specify the he has to sign up and then be able to login if his information in the database.

Lets say you used these rules:

```
 {
"rules": {
   ".read":auth!=null,
   ".write": auth!=null
 }
}
```

It means to read and write in your database the user has to be authenticated to be able to do that.

These rules are just there to determine what the user can do. **But no one will be able to access your console**.

Edit:

If you used this:

```
   {
 "rules": {
   ".read": true,
   ".write": false, 
  }
}
```

Then no one can write anything to the database, so for example I want to add a product in android app, it will be added to the app(graphically) but will not be added to the database, so if I go back to that activity I wont see the product since it was not added in the database(so wont appear when loading the list of products from db).